# Read receipts via php

Tags: php

Ok, so I'm developing an application in which I need to how "how many people" read my email. I've gone through various questions here and developed a small little solution, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Here's the code :-

**checkr.php**

```
<img src="http://localhost/tests/read-receipt/tracking.php?id=1">
```

**tracking.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconnector.php';
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    //increment.
    try
    {
        $s = $conn->query("UPDATE test_number_of_count set count = count+1 where id=1");
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
else
{
    echo "get not set";
}
?>
```

Now if checkr.php is opened, it should update the DB and increase the count, but it doesn't increases. What am I doing wrong ?

Here's my db structure.
[image]

Comment: count is a reserved word.  Try wrapping column in backticks (`) in your SQL

Comment: Shouldn't you use an absolute url rather than a relative one in the `src` property of your image tag?

Comment: @danronmoon
I changed the named to counti and tried. Still doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: @didierc may be on to something.  Just try running the file in your browser and see what happens

Comment: @didierc
I just changed the URL to an absolute URL. Still doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: @danronmoon
I ran the tracking.php file via browser. Throws no errors. Outputs "get not set".

Comment: What does your web server log say?

Comment: @didierc
The logs say actually nothing about the whole process

Comment: Try tracking.php?id=1 in the browser.

Comment: If your server (assuming apache) access logs show nothing, then the problem isn't in your code.

Comment: So basically, `tracker.php` isn't even hit by the email reader? Do you put any other web resources in the email source?

Comment: Side note: most email clients don't display remote images unless the user explicitly allows it. So your counter will most probably only show a fraction of actual reads.

Comment: @danronmoon
Running it directly fixed it. But it's incrementing by +2 everytime I open checkr.php file. What might be causing this ?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it myself. I had a glitch in the `try{}` block. I ran `$conn->query()` and after than ran `$conn->execute()`, therefore executing the query twice. I removed the `$conn->execute()` and everything worked fine. Thanks for the comment guys.